# Processing large files with libsndfile

Tags: c++, wav, libsndfile

Currently I've written a program (in Visual Studio C++) based on the available example code of "libsndfile" in which I've just added a subtraction-function to subtract one (channel of a) WAV-file with another.

The program worked perfectly for files with a limit of 4 channels.

The problem is that as soon as I upload a file with as many as 5 channels or more, the program refuses to execute the function. This is independent of the frame-size as I've managed to process 4-channel files which were many times larger than some 5/6-channel-files which I have used.

Has anyone encountered this or a similar problem before? If requested I will provide the source code.

My apologies for the bad structure, I don't really optimize until I get the whole deal working.

Code:

```
#include <sndfile.hh>
#include <tinyxml2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 32

using TiXmlDocument = tinyxml2::XMLDocument;
using CStdStringA = std::string;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{
    SNDFILE *infile  = NULL;
    SNDFILE *infile2 = NULL;
    SNDFILE *outfile = NULL;
    SF_INFO    sfinfo;
    SF_INFO    sfinfo2;
    SF_INFO    sfinfoOut;
    sf_count_t readcount;
    //int filetype = SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_PCM_24;                  // 24-bit Wav-Files
    TiXmlDocument iDoc;                                               // Init tinyXML
    int i;                                                            // Iteration-var;
    short BufferIn[BLOCK_SIZE];                                       // Buffer1
    short BufferIn2[BLOCK_SIZE];                                      // Buffer2
    short BufferOut[BLOCK_SIZE];
    CStdStringA FileLoc, FileName, FileLocWav, FileLocTxt,FileLocRaw; // OutputFile locationstring
    CStdStringA WavName, WavName2, FileIn, FileIn2;
    FileLoc = "C:\\Testfiles\\";
    //TextTitle(FileLoc);                                             // Print console-header
    printf("Name Wavefile 1:\n");
    std::cin >> WavName;
    FileIn = FileLoc + WavName + ".wav";
    if((infile = sf_open(FileIn.c_str(),SFM_READ,&sfinfo)) == NULL)   // Open Wav-file 2 instance
    {
        printf("Not able to open input file 1\n");
        printf("\n\nPress any key to exit.");                         // Exit-text if file not present
        puts(sf_strerror(NULL)) ;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Wav file 1 succesfully opened." <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nChannels: " << sfinfo.channels << "\nFrames: " << sfinfo.frames << std::endl; // Print Channels & Frames
    std::cout << "Samplerate: " << sfinfo.samplerate << "\n\n" <<  std::endl;// Print Samplerate
    printf("Name Wavefile 2:\n");
    std::cin >> WavName2;
    FileIn2 = FileLoc + WavName2 + ".wav";
    if((infile2 = sf_open(FileIn2.c_str(),SFM_READ,&sfinfo2)) == NULL) // Open Wav-file 2 instance
    {
        printf("Not able to open input file 2\n");
        printf("\n\nPress any key to exit.");                          // Exit-text if file not present
        puts(sf_strerror(NULL)) ;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Wav file 2 succesfully opened." <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nChannels: " << sfinfo2.channels << "\nFrames: " << sfinfo2.frames  << std::endl; // Print Channels & Frames
    std::cout << "Samplerate: " << sfinfo2.samplerate << "\n\n" <<  std::endl;// Print Samplerate
//{
    //std::cout << "Format differs from eachother, abort program.";
    //printf("\n\nPress any key to exit.");                     // Exit-text
    //return 1;
//}
    if(sfinfo.channels != sfinfo2.channels)                                // Abort if channels not the same
    {
        std::cout << "Channelammount differs from eachother, abort program.";
        printf("\n\nPress any key to exit.");                     // Exit-text
        return 1;
    }
    if(sfinfo.samplerate != sfinfo2.samplerate)                   // Abort if samplerate not the same
    {
        std::cout << "Samplerate differs from eachother, abort program.";
        printf("\n\nPress any key to exit.");                     // Exit-text
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Give a filename for Txt- & Wav-file: ";
    std::cin >> FileName;
    FileLoc += FileName;                                          // Fuse Filelocation with given name
    FileLocTxt = FileLoc + ".txt";
    FileLocWav = FileLoc + ".wav";
    FileLocRaw = FileLoc + "Raw.txt";
    sfinfoOut.channels = sfinfo.channels;
    sfinfoOut.format = sfinfo.format;
    sfinfoOut.samplerate = sfinfo.samplerate;
    if((outfile = sf_open(FileLocWav.c_str(),SFM_WRITE,&sfinfoOut)) == NULL)      // Open Wav-file 2 instance
    {
        printf("Not able to create output file \n");
        printf("\n\nPress any key to exit.");                      // Exit-text if file not present
        puts(sf_strerror(NULL)) ;
        return 1;
    }
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(FileLocTxt.c_str(),std::ios::app);
    std::ofstream myfileRaw;
    myfileRaw.open(FileLocRaw.c_str(),std::ios::app);
    while((readcount = sf_read_short(infile, BufferIn, BLOCK_SIZE)))     // While there are still frames to be processed
    {
        //process_data (data, readcount, sfinfo.channels) ;
        auto readcount2 = sf_read_short(infile2, BufferIn2, BLOCK_SIZE);
        for(i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; i++)                                  // BLOCK_SIZE decides the chunk-size
        {
            BufferOut[i] = BufferIn[i] - BufferIn2[i];
            myfileRaw << BufferOut[i];
        }
        sf_write_short(outfile, BufferOut, BLOCK_SIZE) ;                 // Write the data to a new file
    }
    sf_close(infile);                                                    // Close Wav-file handlers
    sf_close(infile2);
    sf_close(outfile);
    myfile.close();                                                      // Close text-file handlers
    printf("\n\nPress any key to exit.");                                // Exit-text
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: made it selfcontained and compiling on linux/gcc with `g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 test.cpp -o test -lsndfile -ltinyxml2`

Comment: Just guessing after a quick read of the documentation: `sf_read_short(infile, BufferIn, BLOCK_SIZE)` seems problematic to start with: sf_read_short is going to read BLOCK_SIZE * #channels so you are writing out of array bounds. There's some stuff on the stack after BufferIn so probably you could get away wih 4 channels because you're lucky, then the UB really kicked in. (sidenote: *please* declare variables as close as possible to where you're going to use them. It makes more sense and it makes code much easier to read. This is not C.)

Comment: Right, does make sense indeed. Problem is that I'm native to writing C for microcontroller-applications and this is a whole new environment for me. Is there any way to give the Buffer-arrays a dynamic size? Where the size represents BLOCK_SIZE * # Channels?

Comment: use `std::vector< short >`, it provides continuous storage with the same semantics as a plain array. It's size can be set in the contructor, or with it's `resize()` method. It has a member function `data()` which gives you a pointer to the beginning of the sequence, that's wht you'd pass to sf_read/sf_write

Comment: @stijn I don't believe your reading of the documentation is accurate and there shouldn't be an overrun.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'll give it a shot and report if it works as supposed to. One thing that did come to mind is the fact that as far as I remember 'sf_read_short()' reads a number of items and sf_readf_short()' reads a number of frames. So I think that only in the 2nd case should the allocation be large enough to hold #items * #channels.
EDIT: Just for testing purposes I only made array-size into BLOCK_SIZE*10. The problem still holds so I doubt it's the allocation.

Comment: I do believe I should explain the result a bit better though. Normally when processing the calculation, it takes about 1 second to 1,5 minutes depending on the frame size and number of channels. Afterward it just displays the 'Press any key to exit.'-message and the program ends. When trying to process channelsizes >= 5, the program finishes up in about half a second and displays the last message as if the calculation went as planned.

Comment: @sehe but it says "Care must be taken to ensure that there is enough space in the array pointed to by ptr, to take (frames * channels) number of items (shorts, ints, floats or doubles)."

Comment: @stijn interesting. Do you have a link, because the page I found explicitely documents something else. Ah, you're looking at `sf_readf_*`, I think. These read _frames_.

Comment: @sehe nevermind.. was looking at sf_readf_xxx instead of sf_read_xxx. So your explanation of BUFFERSIZE not being a multiple of #channels is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation states](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#read):

> #### File Read Functions (Items)
>
> ```
> sf_count_t  sf_read_short   (SNDFILE *sndfile, short *ptr, sf_count_t items) ;
> sf_count_t  sf_read_int     (SNDFILE *sndfile, int *ptr, sf_count_t items) ;
> sf_count_t  sf_read_float   (SNDFILE *sndfile, float *ptr, sf_count_t items) ;
> sf_count_t  sf_read_double  (SNDFILE *sndfile, double *ptr, sf_count_t items) ;
> ```
>
> The file read items functions fill the array pointed to by ptr with the requested number of items. ***The items parameter must be an integer product of the number of channels or an error will occur***

There's your problem, since BLOCK_SIZE *is* a multiple of 1,2,4 but not of 3 and 5 - so that would fail.

About the problem that program completes *as if calculations had taken place*: add appropriate error handling.